# How to unify the electrons and holes in Feynman Diagram?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, feynman-diagrams, greens-functions

As we know, following diagram describes the electron-hole pairs excitation. Namely, the right-going line describes creating electrons propagating with energy $(\omega_n+\nu_n)$, and the left-going line describes the creating  holes propagating with energy $\nu_n$. Thus, the total energy of such "virtual excitation" in system is $(\omega_n+2\nu_n)$.

[image]

However,we can also alter the arrow of the lower line, which gives:

[image]

I think now the physical meaning for the lower lines is: creating electrons with energy $-\nu_n$ propagates, but then the total energy of such virtual excitation will just be $\omega_n$, or, may be it even cannot be considered as virtual excitation.

I am confused of the discrepancy here, there must be some mistakes I have taken.

**Addition:** Comments says if I just switch the arrow like the second figure, the quantum number conservation is not consistent. But does exists some standard procedure if I must want to change the "label arrow" (for standardized automated calculations )?

Comment: The second diagram makes no sense to me: if the ingoing particle is electrically neutral hence you cannot have to electrons in the loop since charge won't be conserved

Comment: On a slightly different note - I have only seen the word "hole" in solid state physics to denote an absence of electrons, not refer to a positron - these terms don't look interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy in the first diagram is conserved, it means that the total energy (or Matsubara frequency) is $i\omega$ in all parts of the diagram. I the middle it is $(i\omega+i\nu)-i\nu$, the second term is subtracted because the corresponding arrow is directed to the left. So I don't think the quantity $i\nu$ is somehow connected with the virtual excitation energy.

To look at virtual excitations we need to take into account the *exact stationary states* $\{\psi_a\}$ available in the system, where the system can spend some time. In order to do it, we can use the spectral representation for the Green function
$$
G(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2,i\nu)=\sum_a\frac{\psi_a(\mathbf{r}_1)\psi^*_a(\mathbf{r}_2)}{i\nu-E_a}.
$$
Thus you diagram can be written as (if the points on the left and on the right are $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $\mathbf{r}_2$)
$$
T\sum_\nu G(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2,i\omega+i\nu)G(\mathbf{r}_2,\mathbf{r}_1,i\nu)=\\
T\sum_{ab\nu}
\frac{\psi_a(\mathbf{r}_1)\psi^*_a(\mathbf{r}_2)}{i\omega+i\nu-E_a}\frac{\psi_b(\mathbf{r}_2)\psi^*_b(\mathbf{r}_1)}{i\nu-E_b}.
$$
After frequency summation we get
$$
\sum_{ab}\psi_a(\mathbf{r}_1)\psi^*_a(\mathbf{r}_2)
\psi_b(\mathbf{r}_2)\psi^*_b(\mathbf{r}_1)
\frac{f_b-f_a}{i\omega+E_b-E_a},
$$
where $f_a$, $f_b$ are occupation numbers.

Here we can see the virtual excitations $b\rightarrow a$, where the particle in the $a$ state and the hole in the $b$ state are created with the total energy $E_a-E_b$. The denominator $i\omega-(E_a-E_b)$ has the typical resonant form of the difference between the actual and virtual energies.

If you want to transform one of the particles into the hole, you may introduce the hole energy $\tilde{E}_b=-E_b$, wave function $\tilde\psi_b=\psi^*_b$, and the occupation number $\tilde{f}_b=1-f_b$ to get the diagram in the explicit form of particle-hole pair propagator:
$$
\sum_{ab\nu}\psi_a(\mathbf{r}_1)\tilde\psi_b(\mathbf{r}_1)\psi^*_a(\mathbf{r}_2)
\tilde\psi^*_b(\mathbf{r}_2)
\frac{1-f_a-\tilde{f}_b}{i\omega-(E_a+\tilde{E_b})}.
$$